# Provisioning profile failed qualification

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to upload app to App Store(from Xcode to iTunesConnect)
My app works with iCloud documents service, everything works fine and provisions are Active.

[image]
[image]

But when i try to Product > Archive > Upload to App Store I've got error with container and after that provisions turns to Invalid

[image]
[image]
I try to delete all my Certificates, changing bundle ID, creating new provisions again and again but every time I've got the same result(
PLEASE HELP ME.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable ICloud in your app ID , then re-create the profiles

[image]

OR edit it and follow configuration steps

[image]

Comment: Ive got it but i use Compatible with Xcode 5 because i use iCloud documents. But now i change it like on your pic and everything is works! Thank you very much!